# How to parse the following json in javascript (ReactNative) having dynamic key value pair?

Tags: javascript, json, api, ecmascript-6

I have the following JSON response coming from an API.

```
{
    "status": true,
    "cakes": {
        "7689": {
            "id": 7689,
            "flavor": "chocolate",
            "cookDetails": {
                "id": 101,
                "firstName": "Name1",
                "lastName": "LastName1"
            }
        },
        "7690": {
            "id": 7690,
            "flavor": "vanilla",
            "cookDetails": {
                "id": 102,
                "firstName": "Name2",
                "lastName": "LastName2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Language I'm using to parse this JSON: Javascript

Framework: ReactNative

**How do I parse it (NOTE: I don't know the value of id in cakes until I parse it)?**

PS: New to the framework. Big thanks.

Comment: JSON.parse(json) ??

Comment: what value do you require ?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. You can parse json the way @sjahan said.

Comment: Parse this: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+parse+json

Comment: You can get the ids using Object.keys(obj.cakes)

Comment: @marvel308 According to the question, OP has a JSON string ...

Comment: @Teemu According to the code in the question, OP has a JSON object. I think the case is that he wants to access the cakes without knowing its' values

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON), how is that?

Comment: Now I feel stupid ;P Thanks for correction @Teemu. Of course, I meant that the OP has already parsed a JSON string and now he has an object with keys which are not known and the question is how to access values under those keys ;)

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek If a question can be interpreted in two totally opposite ways, it might be better not to answer it = ).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about that but I think you want to somehow access a `cake` with id e.x. `7689` without knowing its `id` value. So you have several ways to deal with it. One of them is to iterate over them using `for...in` loop:

```
for(var cakeId in response.cakes){
    var cake = response.cakes[cakeId];

    console.log(cake);
    // Do whatever you want with your cake
}
```

I am sorry if I misunderstood you. If so, please clarify the question by providing us with some examples of what you would like to achieve.

Comment: for..in is generally slow, use Object.keys()

Comment: But if I use Object.keys() I will have an array of keys. So if I want to access each value of the object I have to iterate over the array, have I? Is it still faster than one `for...in` loop?

Comment: yes it is faster to traverse the array than to use for..in

Answer (score 0):

create a function

```
function getCake(obj,key){
let cake = obj['cakes'][key];
return cake;
}
```

call

```
let cakes = {
    "status": true,
    "cakes": {
        "7689": {
            "id": 7689,
            "flavor": "chocolate",
            "cookDetails": {
                "id": 101,
                "firstName": "Name1",
                "lastName": "LastName1"
            }
        },
        "7690": {
            "id": 7690,
            "flavor": "vanilla",
            "cookDetails": {
                "id": 102,
                "firstName": "Name2",
                "lastName": "LastName2"
            }
        }
    }
}

getCake(cakes,'7689');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
const cakesObject = {
    "status": true,
    "cakes": {
        "7689": {
            "id": 7689,
            "flavor": "chocolate",
            "cookDetails": {
                "id": 101,
                "firstName": "Name1",
                "lastName": "LastName1"
            }
        },
        "7690": {
            "id": 7690,
            "flavor": "vanilla",
            "cookDetails": {
                "id": 102,
                "firstName": "Name2",
                "lastName": "LastName2"
            }
        }
    }
};

// this is required only if cakesObject is strigified
const { cakes } = JSON.parse(cakesObject);

const cakesArray = [..Object.values(cakes)];

cakesArray.forEach(cake => {
    const { id } = cake;
    // write further logic
})
```